# AWS Auto Scaling Launch Configuration Encrypted EBS Cloud Formation Example

Tags: encryption, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ebs

I am creating cloud formation script, which will have ELB. In Auto Scaling launch configuration, I want to add encrypted EBS volume. Couldn't find an encrypted property withing blockdevicemapping. I need to encrypt volume. How can I attach an encrypted EBS volume to an EC2 instance through auto scaling launch configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such property for some strange reason when using launch configurations, however it is there when using blockdevicemappings with simple EC2 instances. See
[launchconfig-blockdev](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig-blockdev-template.html) vs [ec2-blockdev](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-blockdev-template.html)

So you'll either have to use simple instances instead of autoscaling groups, or you can try this workaround:

*SnapshotIds* are accepted for launchconf blockdev too, and as stated [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html) "Snapshots that are taken from encrypted volumes are automatically encrypted. Volumes that are created from encrypted snapshots are also automatically encrypted."

Create a snapshot from an encrypted *empty* EBS volume and use it in the CloudFormation template. If your template should work in multiple regions then of course you'll have to create the snapshot in every region and use a Mapping in the template.

Answer (score 3):

As Marton says, there is no such property (unfortunately it often takes a while for CloudFormation to catch up with the main APIs).

Normally each encrypted volume you create will have a different key. However, when using the workaround mentioned (of using an encrypted snapshot) the resulting encrypted volumes will inherit the encryption key from the snapshot and all be the same.

From a cryptography point of view this is a bad idea as you potentially have multiple, different volumes and snapshots with the same key. If an attacker has access to all of these then he can potentially use differences to infer information about the key more easily.

An alternative is to write a script that creates and attaches a new encrypted volume at the boot time of a instance. This is fairly easy to do. You'll need to give the instance permissions to create and attach volumes and either have installed the AWS CLI tool or a library for your preferred scripting language. One you have that you can, from the instance that is booting, create a volume and attach it.

You can find a starting point for such a script here: https://github.com/guardian/machine-images/blob/master/packer/resources/features/ebs/add-encrypted.sh

Answer (score 2):

There is an AutoScaling EBS Block Device type which provides the "Encrypted" option:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig-blockdev-template.html

Hope this helps!